# Implementing background processing

Tags: linux, process

UPDATE:
There was an obvious debugging step I forget. What happens if I try a command like `ps &`
in the regular old bash shell? The answer is that I see the same behavior. For example:

```
[ahoffer@uw1-320-21 ~/program1]$ ps &
[1] 30166
[ahoffer@uw1-320-21 ~/program1]$   PID TTY          TIME CMD
26423 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
30166 pts/0    00:00:00 ps
<no prompt!>
```

If I then press Enter, the command shell reports the exit status and the console displays the exit status and the prompt:

```
[ahoffer@uw1-320-21 ~/program1]$ ps&
[1] 30166
[ahoffer@uw1-320-21 ~/program1]$   PID TTY          TIME CMD
26423 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
30166 pts/0    00:00:00 ps

[1]    Done                          ps
[ahoffer@uw1-320-21 ~/program1]$
```

PS: I am using PuttY to access the Linux machine via SSH on port 22.

---

ORIGINAL QUESTION:
I am working on a homework assignment. The task is to implement part of a command shell interpreter on Linux using functions like fork(), exec(). I have a strange bug that occurs when my code executes a command as a background process.

For example, in the code below, the command `ls` correctly executes ls and prints its output to the console. When the command is finished, the The event loop in the calling code correctly prints the prompt, "% ", to the console.

However, when `ls &` is executed, `ls` executes correctly and its output is printed to the console. However, the prompt, " %", is never printed!

The code is simple. Here is what the pseudo code looks like:

```
int child_pid;

if ( (child_pid=fork()) == 0 )  {

   //child process
   ...execute the command...
}

else {

    //Parent process
    if( delim == ';' )    

        waidpid(child_pid);
}

//end of function.
```

The parent process blocks if the delimiter is a semicolon. Otherwise the function ends and the code re-enters the event loop. However, if the parent sleeps while the the background command executes, the prompt appears correctly:

...

```
//Parent process
        if( delim == ';' ) {

        waidpid(child_pid)
   }

    else if( delim == '&' ) {

        sleep(1); 
        //The prompt, " %", is correctly printed to the
        // console when the parent wakes up.
    }
```

No one in class knows why this happens. The OS is RedHat Enterprise 5 and the compiler is g++.

Comment: You should show your real code, not pseudo code. And I strongly suggest studying what simple existing shells -e.g. `sash`- do (by reading their source code). I don't understand the details of your question (and why the `sleep(1)` in your code)?

Comment: You can also use `strace` (or also `ltrace`) on simple existing shells to understand the system calls they are doing. Maybe your question is related to process groups and controlling terminals.

Comment: Instead of a quickly running command like `ls` try some command lasting more time, like `sleep 2` (or write your own C test program running for more than a second).

Comment: Are you certain the prompt is not simply being printed before the output of ls?

Comment: I'll look into strace and ltrace. I tried them briefly in the bash shell for "ls" they produced pages of information. If I had another week or two I would look through the source code, but the professor made clear to me he doesn't want me to burn much more time on the assignment-- he wants me to move on to POSIX threads and then Java threads. So thanks for the input. Given the time and need, I would dig into open source code and the trace commands.

Comment: The edit you did with putting the answer inside the question is wrong. Add that part as an answer to your question.